# How to solve integration by parts

Tags: integration

![][1]

So i have this definite integral:

$$\int_{\sqrt[3]{4}}^{\sqrt[3]{3+e}}x^2 \ln(x^3-3)\,dx.$$

I thought of using integration by parts. So
\begin{align}
u & =\ln(x^3-3) \\[8pt]
du & =\frac{3x^2}{x^3-3} \\[8pt]
dv & =x^2 \, dx \\[8pt]
v & =\frac{x^3} 3
\end{align}

Comment: $t=x^3-3$, then $dt = 3x^2$, then $\ldots$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Well with IBP woulds u we equal to all ln?

Comment: As for me, substitution $t=x^3-3$ helps faster than IBP: $t_1 = (\sqrt[3]{4})^3-3 = 4-3=1$, $t_2 = \ldots$, then integral will have simple form $\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\ln (t) dt$.

Comment: Okay thanks! Could you please write your steps as an answer here??

Comment: Please don't care about it: comment is OK too.

Comment: How would i plug in the t's ? it looks pretty hard , especially the one with the square root of e involved.?

Comment: If i use u subsition, then clearly i would have to use integration by parts, am i correct?

Comment: Yes, correct: substitution $t=x^3-3$ everywhere:
$$t_1 = (\sqrt[3]{4})^3-3 = 4-3=1;$$
$$t_2 = (\sqrt[3]{3+e})^3-3 = (3+e)-3=e;$$

$$\dfrac{1}{3}\int_{\sqrt[3]{4}}^{\sqrt[3]{3+e}} \ln\left(x^3-3\right) \underbrace{3x^2 dx}_{dt}=\dfrac{1}{3}\int_{1}^{e} \ln(t) {dt}.$$
At this step: IBP ($u=\ln(t)$, $dv=dt$, so $v=t$, $du=\dfrac{dt}{t}$), so 
$$\dfrac{1}{3}\int_1^e\ln(t)dt = \left[ uv|_1^e - \int_1^evdu\right]=\dfrac{1}{3}\left(t\ln(t)|_1^e - \int_1^e dt\right)=$$ $$\dfrac{1}{3}\Bigl(e\cdot 1 - 1\cdot 0 - (e-1)\Bigr)=\dfrac{1}{3}(e-0-e+1)=\dfrac{1}{3}.$$

Comment: Why is this question getting down-voted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrating by parts:
$$\begin{align}
\int_{\sqrt[3]{4}}^{\sqrt[3]{3+e}}x^2 \ln(x^3-3)\,dx & =\ln(x^3-3)\cdot \frac{x^3}{3}\bigg{|}_{\sqrt[3]{4}}^{\sqrt[3]{3+e}}-\int_{\sqrt[3]{4}}^{\sqrt[3]{3+e}}\frac{x^3}{3}\cdot \frac{3x^2}{x^3-3}\,dx\\
& =\frac{3+e}{3}-\int_{\sqrt[3]{4}}^{\sqrt[3]{3+e}}\frac{x^5}{x^3-3}dx=\\
& =\frac{3+e}{3}-\frac13\int_{\sqrt[3]{4}}^{\sqrt[3]{3+e}}\frac{x^3}{x^3-3} \, d(x^3)\\
& =\frac{3+e}{3}-\frac13\int_{\sqrt[3]{4}}^{\sqrt[3]{3+e}}\frac{x^3-3+3}{x^3-3} \, d(x^3)\\
& =\frac{3+e}{3}-\frac13\left(x^3+3\ln(x^3-3)\right)\bigg{|}_{\sqrt[3]{4}}^{\sqrt[3]{3+e}} \\
& =\frac{3+e}{3}-\frac13\left(6+e-4\right) \\
& =\frac{1}{3}
\end{align}$$

Integration by substitution:
$$t=x^3-3 \Rightarrow dt=3x^2dx\\
\int_{\sqrt[3]{4}}^{\sqrt[3]{3+e}}x^2 \ln(x^3-3)\,dx=\\
\frac13 \int_1^e \ln t dt=\frac13 (t\ln t|_1^e-\int_1^e t\cdot \frac 1tdt)=\\
\frac13(e-e+1)=\frac13.$$

Comment: How do you plug in the t's^

Comment: And were do you get the t's to be equal to e and 1? please help

Comment: your second question, it is because: $t_1=(\sqrt[3]{4})^3-3=1$ and $t_2=(\sqrt[3]{3+e})^3-3=e$. What do you mean by plugging t's?

Comment: Oh, I see Oleg567 already gave detailed solution above, I was focusing on my answer here.

Comment: But what do you do with that then ? The e and the 1 ? the answer would be e-1. Not 1/3. Why are you plugging the e and the 1 back into the integral? What about the ln ? at this point i am extremely confuseed.

Answer (score 3):

As user Oleg567 suggested in the comments, the $u$-substitution with $u=x^3-3$ works much more efficiently than integration by parts. However, if you're interested in using integration by parts here, I'll provide a sketch of how to use it below.

As you've already written, we'll take

\begin{align*}
u &=\ln(x^3-3)\quad&\quad dv&=x^2\,dx\\
du &=\frac{3x^2}{x^3-3}\,dx\quad &\quad v&=\frac13 x^3
\end{align*}
The formula for integration by parts is $\int u\,dv=uv-\int v\,du$, so plugging in our parameters above, we have

$$
\int x^2\ln(x^3-3)\,dx=\frac{1}{3}x^3\ln(x^3-3)-\int\frac{x^5}{x^3-3}\,dx.
$$

As messy as it is this last integral can be solved by first using long division to get the fraction into a proper fraction form (where the degree of the numerator is less than the degree of the denominator) and then using a $u$-substitution.

Comment: Okay ! I tried it with u subsitution and it seems all good until i have to plug the t values of the integral ... how do i do that ? especially with the cube root of 3 plus e?

Comment: @SaraSalvante: In all cases, you end up cubing a cube root, so the cube root goes away. This makes the calculations a breeze.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Write your integral in the form
$$\frac{1}{3}\int 3x^2\ln(x^3-3)dx$$ and Substitute $$t=x^3-3$$

Comment: How did you get to that form?

Comment: Since $$dt=3x^2dx$$ the derivative of the argument of the log function stands in front of the integral

Comment: Ok. So indeed i am not doing anything but re-writing the integral in a simple form. Then all i have to do is subsitute the t values?

Comment: Yes this is true, should i post you the result?

Comment: yes please!!!!!!

Comment: I have got $$1/3$$

Comment: The indefinite integral is given by $$-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{1}{3} x^3 \log \left(x^3-3\right)-\log \left(3-x^3\right)$$

Comment: I am currently subsituting the two t's into the equation that you wrote above, under Hint: Write your integral in the form. Seems kind of tricky subsituting especially with the e's involved .. how do you do that '

Answer (score 1):

I would have done it like this:
\begin{align}
v & = x^3-3 \\[6pt]
dv & = 3x^2 \, dx \\[6pt]
\frac{dv} 3 & = x^2 \, dx
\end{align}
As $x$ goes from $\sqrt[3]4$ to $\sqrt[3]{3+e},$ then $v$ goes from $1$ to $e,$ so we have
$$
\int_{\sqrt[3]4}^{\sqrt[3]{3+e}} x^2 \ln(x^3-3) \, dx = \frac 1 3 \int_1^e \ln v\, dv
$$
Then I would integrate by parts, as follows:
\begin{align}
\frac 1 3 \int \ln v \, dv & = \frac 1 3 \int u\, dv & \text{with } u = \ln v \\[10pt]
& = \frac 1 3 \left( vu - \int v\,du \right) \\[10pt]
& = \frac 1 3 \left( v\ln v - \int v\, \frac{dv} v \right) \\[10pt]
& = \frac 1 3 \left( v\ln v - \int dv \right) \\[10pt]
& = \frac 1 3 \left[ v\ln v - v \vphantom{\frac 11} \right]_1^e = \frac 1 3.
\end{align}

Here's an alternative to integration by parts:

\begin{align}
& \int_1^e (\log_e v)\,dv \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_1^e \left( \int_1^v \frac 1 w \, dw \right) \, dv \\[10pt]
= {} & \iint\limits_{1\,\le\, w\,\le\, v\,\le \,e} \frac 1 w \, d(v,w) \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_1^e \left( \int_w^e \frac 1 w \,dv \right)\, dw \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_1^e \frac{e-w} w \, dw \\[10pt]
= {} & \Big[ e(\log_e w) - w \Big]_1^e \\[10pt]
= {} & 1. \end{align}

Comment: @farruhota : $v$ goes from $\ln1$ to $\ln e,$ i.e. from $0$ to $1.$ I fixed some typos.

Comment: Can somebody show me how to integrate by u subsitituion this question?

Comment: @SaraSalvante : I doubt you can do it without either integration by parts or something more complicated. My answer had some flaws, having been written hastily, but I deleted it, then edited it further, then undeleted it. $\qquad$

Comment: @SaraSalvante: Your options are either to (i) integrate by parts, then apply a $u$-substitution (as I did in my answer) or (ii) to use a $u$-substitution then apply integration by parts. Either way, you're going to be using both techniques. +$1$ for this answer.

Comment: @SaraSalvante : Here's an alternative to integration by parts: $$ \begin{align} & \int_1^e (\log_e v)\,dv \\ \\ = {} & \int_1^e \left( \int_1^v \frac 1 w \, dw \right) \, dv \\ \\ = {} & \iint\limits_{1\,\le\, w\,\le\, v\,\le \,e} \frac 1 w \, d(v,w) \\ \\ = {} & \int_1^e \left( \int_w^e \frac 1 w \,dv \right)\, dw \\ \\ = {} & \int_1^e \frac{e-w} w \, dw \\ \\ = {} & \Big[ e(\log_e w) - w \Big]_1^e \\ \\ = {} & 1. \end{align} $$